# Error while using w, h = template.shape[::-1]

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting an error:

```
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('opencv-template-matching-python-tutorial.jpg')

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('opencv-template-for-matching.jpg',0)

w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

threshold = 0.8

loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):

    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Detected',img_rgb)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with `opencv`, but that error means that `cv2.imread('opencv-template-for-matching.jpg',0)` fails to read that file and thus returns `None`.

Make sure that this file exists and in the supported format.
From `imread`'s [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread):

> The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it. **If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL)**. Currently, the following file formats are supported:
>   Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib (always supported)
>   JPEG files - *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.jpe (see the Notes section)
>   JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2 (see the Notes section)
>   Portable Network Graphics - *.png (see the Notes section)
>   Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm (always supported)
>   Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras (always supported)
>   TIFF files - *.tiff, *.tif (see the Notes section)

Comment: I would consider this a bug (or at least bad API design) in `cv2.imread`; if it can't open the requested file, it should raise an exception, not return `None`. That said, it's the user's responsibility to check the return value to make sure the operation succeeded before trying to use the return value.